# Query gives one indexed array with many elements

Tags: php, mysqli

I have code like this:

```
$ch = @new mysqli ($config['db']['host'],$config['db']['user'],$config['db']['password'],$config['db']['database']);
if($result = $ch->query("SELECT pid FROM posts"))
{
   while($pids = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        var_dump($pids);
    }
```

var_dump gives me:

```
array(1) { ["pid"]=> string(1) "1" } array(1) { ["pid"]=> string(1) "2" } array(1) { ["pid"]=> string(1) "3" } array(1) { ["pid"]=> string(1) "4" }
```

I have two problems:

1. In database column 'pid' is  an int type but the query yields an array of strings
2. All records from database (4) are saved in one row in an array (got only one index)

Because of that I can't use max(), because it gives me all records (4321).

Comment: Explain your problem **Properly**!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have got 4. Check correctly. The `var_dump()` executes four times, returning a single array (column - row values):

```
array(1) {
  ["pid"]=> string(1) "1"
}
array(1) {
  ["pid"]=> string(1) "2"
}
array(1) {
  ["pid"]=> string(1) "3"
}
array(1) {
  ["pid"]=> string(1) "4"
}
```

If you want everything to be in a single variable, use:

```
$allPids = array();
while (false != ($pids = $result->fetch_assoc())) {
  $allPids[] = $pids;
}
var_dump($allPids);
```

Comment: It gives me something like that

`array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["pid"]=> string(1) "1" } }    
array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { ["pid"]=> string(1) "1" } [1]=> array(1) { ["pid"]=> string(1) "2" } }     
array(3) { [0]=> array(1) { ["pid"]=> string(1) "1" } [1]=> array(1) { ["pid"]=> string(1) "2" } [2]=> array(1) { ["pid"]=> string(1) "3" } }     
array(4) { [0]=> array(1) { ["pid"]=> string(1) "1" } [1]=> array(1) { ["pid"]=> string(1) "2" } [2]=> array(1) { ["pid"]=> string(1) "3" } [3]=> array(1) { ["pid"]=> string(1) "4" } }`

Comment: @TomaszSiemiński Change to `$allPids[] = $pids["pid"];` and you can use the `max` function like `max($allPids);`.

Comment: `$allPids[] = $pids['pid'];`
`echo max($allPids);`
It gives all pid's from query (1234)

Comment: @TomaszSiemiński Just saw it is taking the string value. Use `$allPids[] = intval($pids["pid"]);` and please don't unaccept after accepting. Do only when people don't respond. When people are busy in the day job, respect for their time to help you.

Comment: Sorry for that. I used it, they are now an int's but `max()` still gives me all of them.

Comment: @TomaszSiemiński Lemme try it out for you buddy. Give me a few mins.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store them in one `array` first.

```
while($pids = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    $array[] = $pids;
}
var_dump($array);
```

And for the data type **PHP** will cast them accordingly.